# reading multiple lines from file into array of structs c

Tags: c, arrays, struct, newline, scanf

I'm trying to read data from a file into an array of structures to use later for a hash table. I finally stored to data from 1st line into a struct successfully, however, when reading from 2nd line, the output of the information is not correct.

this is part of the sample data

"K300"   "Keyboard"  "US Generic" 150.00 50

"R576" "16-inch Rims"   "Toyota Verossa" 800.00 48

"HL412" "Headlight" "Ford Taurus 2010" 600.00 52

and this is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define n 99

typedef struct partInfo {
  char number[6];
  char name[20];
  char description[30];
  double price;
  int qty;
}Part;

Part part[n]; 

int main() {

char num[6], name[20], desc[30], space[10];
int q, i = 0;
double p;
char ch;

FILE * in = fopen("input.txt", "r");

fscanf(in,"\"%[^\"]", &num);
               fscanf(in,"\"%[^\"]", &space);

               fscanf(in, "\"%[^\"]", &name);
               fscanf(in,"\"%[^\"]", &space);

               fscanf(in, " \"%[^\"]s\"", desc);
               fscanf(in, "%[^ ]s", &space);

               fscanf(in,"%lf", &p);
               fscanf(in, "%[^ ]s", &space);

               fscanf(in, " %d", &q);
               fscanf(in, "%[^\n]s", &space);

               strcpy(part[i].number, num);
               strcpy(part[i].name, name);
               strcpy(part[i].description, desc);
               part[i].price = p;
               part[i].qty = q;


printf("%s\n", part[i].number);
printf("%s\n", part[i].name);
printf("%s\n", part[i].description);
printf("%.2f\n", part[i].price);
printf("%d\n\n", part[i].qty);
fscanf(in,"%[^\n]", &space); // right here seems to be the problem getting to next line

               fscanf(in, "\"%[^\"]", &name);
               fscanf(in,"\"%[^\"]", &space);

               fscanf(in, " \"%[^\"]s\"", desc);
               fscanf(in, "%[^ ]s", &space);

               fscanf(in,"%lf", &p);
               fscanf(in, "%[^ ]s", &space);
               fscanf(in, " %d", &q);

               i++;
               strcpy(part[i].number, num);
               strcpy(part[i].name, name);
               strcpy(part[i].description, desc);
               part[i].price = p;
               part[i].qty = q;

printf("%s\n", part[i].number);
printf("%s\n", part[i].name);
printf("%s\n", part[i].description);
printf("%.2f\n", part[i].price);
printf("%d\n\n", part[i].qty);
fscanf(in,"\"%[^\"]", &space);

fclose(in);
return 0;
}
```

I didn't want to use a while loop as yet, I wanted to see if I can get the code working properly before implementing the while loop

Comment: "the information is not correct": in what way(s)?

Comment: the output comes out as

k300 

keyboard 

us generic 

150.00 

50

and for the 2nd line of data it comes out as

k300

keyboard

R576

150.00

50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that like this.

```
fscanf(in, " \"%[^\"]", num);
fscanf(in, "\"%[^\"]s", space);

fscanf(in, " \"%[^\"]", name);
fscanf(in, "\"%[^\"]",space);

fscanf(in, " \"%[^\"]", desc);
fscanf(in, "%[^ ]s", space);

fscanf(in, "%lf", &p);
fscanf(in, "%[^ ]s",space);

fscanf(in, "%d", &q);
fscanf(in, "%[^\n]s", &space);
```

Comment: wow! it's always the smallest things. Thanks a lot, saved me there :)